# Telebot при попытке редактировать фотография выдает ошибку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, pil

Ошибка:

```
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message can't be edited
```

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from PIL import Image
bot=telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN,parse_mode='MARKDOWN')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def photo(message):
    im1 = Image.open("wat.jpg")
    if im1.mode in ("RGBA", "P"): im1 = im1.convert("RGB")
    print('message.photo =', message.photo)
    fileID = message.photo[-1].file_id
    print('fileID =', fileID)
    file_info = bot.get_file(fileID)
    print('file.file_path =', file_info.file_path)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
with open("image.jpg", 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
        im2 = Image.open("image.jpg")
        im2.paste(im1)
        im2.save('ready.jpg')
        bot.edit_message_media(message_id=message.id, chat_id="-1001955379695",
media=types.InputMediaPhoto(im2))
        new_file.close()
        im2.close()
        im1.close()


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: бот может редактировать только свои сообщения, видимо ошибка об этом и сообщает

Comment: Оступы, так и задумано?

Comment: @СергейШ не, тут криво отобразилось